# Do C#9 Record Types Take Longer to Perform Equality Comparisons than Classes?

Tags: c#, equality, comparison-operators, c#-9.0

A colleague of mine ran an experiment where he compared the speed of equality comparison between a C#9 record type and a class. The two types were identical in everything other than being a class, or a record (they have the same fields). Furthermore, the class version he wrote calculates the hash code of the object during construction (since it's a class with only read-only getters that cannot be mutated throughout its life).

We noticed that equality comparison is slower with record types than class types that are otherwise identical. Why is this? Is GetHashCode invoked every time a record type undergoes an equality comparison?

I've attached the test code below, as well as the result of the test.

```cs
[SetUpFixture]
public class SetupTrace
{
    [OneTimeSetUp]
    public void StartTest()
    {
        Trace.Listeners.Add(new ConsoleTraceListener());
    }

    [OneTimeTearDown]
    public void EndTest()
    {
        Trace.Flush();
    }
}

namespace TestProject1
{
    [TestFixture]
    public class Tests
    {
        [Test]
        public void Test1()
        {
            var dog = new DogClass(true, 1);
            var dogSame = new DogClass(true, 1);
            var dogDifferent = new DogClass(true, 2);

            var dogRecord = new DogRecord(true, 1);
            var dogRecordSame = new DogRecord(true, 1);
            var dogRecordDifferent = new DogRecord(true, 2);

            var sw = new Stopwatch();


            sw.Restart();

            for (ulong i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i)
                Equals(dog, dogSame);

            sw.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine($"Class same took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");

            sw.Restart();

            for (ulong i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i)
                Equals(dogRecord, dogRecordSame);

            sw.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine($"Record same took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");



            sw.Restart();

            for (ulong i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i)
                Equals(dog, dogDifferent);

            sw.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine($"Class different took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");

            sw.Restart();

            for (ulong i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i)
                Equals(dogRecord, dogRecordDifferent);

            sw.Stop();

            Console.WriteLine($"Record different took {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds} ms");
        }

        public class DogClass
        {
            private int _hashCode = 0;

            public bool IsMale { get; }
            public int InstrumentCount { get; }

            public DogClass(bool isMale, int instrumentCount)
            {
                IsMale = isMale;
                InstrumentCount = instrumentCount;
                _hashCode = GenerateHashCode(IsMale, InstrumentCount);
            }

            public override bool Equals(object obj)
            {
                if (!(obj is DogClass other))
                    return false;

                return
                    IsMale == other.IsMale && InstrumentCount == other.InstrumentCount;
            }

            public override int GetHashCode() => _hashCode;
        }

        public record DogRecord(bool IsMale, int InstrumentCount);

        public static class HashCodeGenerator
        {
            public static int Generate(params object[] fields)
            {
                if (fields == null) { throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(fields)); }

                bool hasField = false;
                int hash = 1;
                for (int i = 0; i < fields.Length; ++i)
                {
                    if (fields[i] != null)
                    {
                        hasField = true;
                        unchecked
                        {
                            hash += hash * _prime + fields[i].GetHashCode();
                        }
                    }
                }

                if (hasField == false) { throw new Exception("At least one (1) non-null field is required to generate a hash code."); }

                return hash;
            }

            private const int _prime = 92821;
        }
    }
}
```

The results of the equality tests are:

```
Class same took 13190 ms
Record same took 23287 ms
Class different took 5704 ms
Record different took 13347 ms
```

Comment: Records have a protected `EqualityContract` property of type `Type` that it compares before comparing the properties.  That involves a call to `Type.op_Equality`, so there's *that*. Of course they're going to be different if you haven't implemented your class the same way.

Comment: Records also use `EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals` for *everything*, even when `T` is a primitive type. Again, different implementations, different results.

Comment: Also, Stopwatch isn't a benchmarking tool, and woefully inadequate to ascertain empirical evidence for performance

Comment: @TheGeneral Any recommendations instead of Stopwatch?

Comment: Yeah sure, take a look at BenchmarkDotNet, its very easy to use, and saves you from falling into some very common traps when benchmarking

Comment: @TheGeneral - I wouldn't say "woefully inadequate". Perhaps not even "inadequate". You have to know what you're doing to avoid GCs getting in the way, but I always thought that `Stopwatch` was pretty good. Can you please explain why you think it's woefully inadequate?

Comment: @TheGeneral - Also, BenchmarkDotNet uses the same kernel32.dll calls that `Stopwatch` uses to do timing. Is the inadequacies just around the scafolding you have to put around `Stopwatch` to make sure its results are meaningful?

Comment: @Enigmativity \*looks up\*, if you were to use great test methodologies, you could use the little hand on the clock on the wall and get great results. Which was hardly the point of the comment. A benchmarking tool, helps you create accurate performance tests by alerting you to problems before you even run the tests, cancels out any jitting problems, dependency loading, test ordering. Also test run multiple times, removes outlier's, warms up code, collects before each run, <Add your favorite reason here>.

Comment: And if nothing else, forces you into a common pattern and allows you to reason about the tests you are writing in a standard framework. Also, i find it strange we are even having this conversation

Comment: @TheGeneral - Only because I think you gave the impression that `Stopwatch` was faulty in some way. For what it does, it is stellar, but, as with any tool, it needs to be in the hands of a master to get good results.